# How to get Id of Card View in Custom dialog

Tags: android, dialog

I have Created a Custom Dialog and want to get id Of a Card View in it. in the OnClick method I am not getting any response from the id. How can I make the Toast Show bly clicking on the card view?

```
public class CustomDialogClass extends Dialog implements
        android.view.View.OnClickListener {
    CardView Per25cardView;
    CardView Per40cardView;

    public CustomDialogClass(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);

        Per25cardView=findViewById(R.id.per25);
        Per40cardView=findViewById(R.id.per40);
    }




    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.per25:
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "card view Here we come", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check the variables `Per25cardView` and `Per40cardView` after the assignments in `onCreate()` if they are `null` or not?

Comment: @mTak No I didn't. How to check?

Comment: @Umair check my answer i will work for you

Comment: After the assignments add: `if  (Per25cardView == null) Toast.makeText(this, "Per25cardView==null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` if you see a toast when you run the app then it is null.

Comment: @MilanPansuriya Thanks! It worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the click listener to view

```
Per25cardView=findViewById(R.id.per25);
Per25cardView.setOnClickListner(this);
```